# Finding the Corresponding AOSP Branch for a Specific Android Binary (Tiramisu TP1A.221005.002.B2) for Pixel 4 XL

Tags: android, repo, android-13

I am currently trying to initialize, sync, build, customize, and deploy AOSP onto my Pixel 4 XL phone, which supports Android 13 out of the box after a factory reset. The precise binary it supports is the latest Tiramisu (Android 13) version TP1A.221005.002.B2. The corresponding binary can be found at this link: https://developers.google.com/android/drivers#coraltp1a.221005.002.b2.

I'm encountering an issue because I am uncertain about the corresponding branch in the AOSP manifest that would match the code used for this binary or vendor image. I want to execute the repo init command using this pattern:

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-13.0.0

However, I am struggling to identify the correct placeholder for  that corresponds with my device's binary version.

I've been trying to find a mapping or correlation between the branch and the vendor image but haven't been successful so far. For reference, here's the link to the AOSP manifest with all its branches and tags: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/.

I'd appreciate it if someone could assist me in determining the appropriate branch/tag/commit that correlates with my Android version. How can I find the correct mapping between the AOSP branch and the vendor image for the release version?

Thank you for your help.